# Difference in size of HTML file directly downloaded from Google Drive and via Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I uploaded a word document on Google Drive. I am downloading the file in HTML format in following two ways.

1. First method: I open the file in Google Docs and then downloaded the file: File -> Download as -> Web page (.html, zipped). I unzip the tar and then I get the HTML file. Its size is 62 kB.
2. Second method: I used Drive API v3 to create (or upload) the word document to Google Drive. Then I exported the file to HTML format. Its size is 173 kB.

My question is why there is difference of almost three times in size of HTML file? What should be done to get the same file size (62 kB) when downloading (or exporting) using Drive API?

This is the Drive API code I am using to create and export the file.

```
    Drive service = getDriveService();

    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setName("Test Document");
    fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.document");

    FileContent fileContent = new FileContent("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", new java.io.File("/home/test/test.doc"));
    File createResponse = service.files().create(fileMetadata, fileContent).execute();

    java.io.File parentDir = new java.io.File("/home/test/");
    if (!parentDir.exists()) {
        throw new IOException("Parent directory does not exists.");
    }
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(parentDir, "Test Document"));
    service.files().export(createResponse.getId(), "text/html").executeAndDownloadTo(out);
```

Kindly help me with this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you took a look inside the files? Use a file comparator and see the diffrences.

Comment: @Luftbaum: Yes, I did took a look inside the files using file comparator. There were lot many style tags in the HTML file exported using Drive API.

But there is no difference in the output of both the HTML files when viewed in browser.

Comment: There you got it. Now you have to think about it. Does those few kb really matter? If yes, try to take a look in the Google Drive Settings. I think there is a way to turn it off, somehow

Comment: Yes, those few kB (almost three times) really matter. Do you know what changes needs to be made to Drive API code so that I can get smaller HTML output (62 kB instead of 173 kB).

Comment: Never used it, sorry. But Google is your friend (except Drive this case ^^). Just search for Export Settings or something like that. Maybe Drive allready added it after the upload.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Luftbaum. I will wait for Google Drive API team or someone who knows about this to help me with this issue.

Comment: Those 'many style tags' are not kb free. A 100 words document doesn't have the same size as a 200 words document. Numbers of characters involved can make a difference. Not sure if this is applicable to your situation but if you happen to be using URI requests, use [Partial Responses](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/performance). By specifying the 'fields' you want returned, Drive API won't give you lots of unnecessary data, saving you byte sizes.